# Error with merging csv files - TypeError: read_csv() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filepath_or_buffer'

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I try to merge csv files in python3.8.
My files merge.csv, merge2.csv, merge3.csv
When i try to delete unicode escape, i got decode error.

And i got this output

```
Merging multiple CSV files...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merge2.py", line 10, in <module>
    map(pd.read_csv(encoding="unicode_escape"), [file1, file2]), ignore_index=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 317, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: read_csv() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filepath_or_buffer'
```

My python code:

```
import glob
import os

# setting the path for joining multiple files
files = os.path.join("/home/buraksoylemez.com/merge/", "merge*.csv")

# list of merged files returned
files = glob.glob(files)

print("Resultant CSV after joining all CSV files at a particular location...");

# joining files with concat and read_csv
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv(encoding="unicode_escape"), files), ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to map variables inside [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), you may look at [**`itertools.starmap`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap).

Otherwise, you can use this :

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

# setting the path for joining multiple files
path = os.path.join("/home/buraksoylemez.com/merge/")

# list of merged files returned
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path , "merge*.csv"))

print("Resultant CSV after joining all CSV files at a particular location...")

all_dfs ={}

for filename in files:
    all_dfs[filename] = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding="unicode_escape")
     
df = pd.concat(all_dfs, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```